I extracted files of android studio files and check on start android studio but android studio not opening
I installed android studios on my laptop but after extracting all files and ticking on start android studio it doesn't started an it didn't show on desktop or any other location what can i do
when i checked on start android studio it should launch android studio or it should show it on desktop

You forgot to add some details about your OS (Windows, Linux, MacOS, and the used version) and also about your hardware (COU and RAM).
